# How to bind a service into any host's port?

Tags: linux, service, port

I was wondering how services (like mysql, apache, mongoDB) are bind against a port in the server/local machine. How does this work?

I'm guessing that when the service starts, it tries to connect to the port and if possible, the service is "paused" until the OS receives a request against the selected port. Is there any documentation out explaining how this works?

Comment: You use Linux kernel system calls. First you create a [socket](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/socket.2.html) and [bind](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/bind.2.html) it to a port, then you [listen](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/listen.2.html) for and [accept](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/accept.2.html) incoming requests. There are plenty of books and tutorials out there. Answering this in detail goes beyond what stackoverflow is for. Try some and come back with more specific questions.

Answer (score 0):

May I help you?

This is a **[list of TCP and UDP port numbers used](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_TCP_and_UDP_port_numbers)** by protocols for operation of network applications.

The Transmission Control Protocol (TCP) and the User Datagram Protocol (UDP) only need one port for duplex, bidirectional traffic. They usually use port numbers that match the services of the corresponding TCP or UDP implementation, if they exist.

Comment: How the implementation works? I'm asking because I want to understand how my server is bind against the machine, and how the OS calls the service when a request is made against a TCP/UDP port.